# Change return values based on replaced extended method within class

Tags: typescript

I have a class `FileHandler` and then a `FileOrNullHandler` class that extends the original.

The issue is that the inherited methods from `FileHandler` within `FileOrNullHandler` are stuck with the authored return type from the original class.

```
export class FileHandler {
    static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
        const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
        const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
        return { path, encoding, flag, content };
    }
    static async readFile (a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File> {
        if (typeof a === 'string') a = FileQueryHandler.getFromPath(a, b);
        return this.readFileFromFileQuery(a);
    }
    static async readFiles (a: (Path | FileQuery)[] | Directory, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {        
        if (a instanceof Array) return Promise.all(a.map(p => this.readFile(p, b)));
        return this.readFiles(PathHandler.getFromDirectory(a), b);
    }
    static async readFilesFromDirectory(a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {
        const ps = await DirectoryHandler.readDirectory(a);    
        if (typeof a === 'string') return await (this).readFiles(ps, b);
        return await this.readFiles(ps, a);
    }
}

export class FileOrNullHandler extends FileHandler {
    static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File | null> {
        return orNull(() => FileHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(fq));
    }
}
```

I see one of two options for getting the proper types here.

1. Set relative return types of original methods based on `this`. (may not be possible)
2. Overwrite the method `ReturnType` within `FileOrNullHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

A general tenant of OOP is that a derived class should be able to replace a base class. In this case the derived class can't replace the base class since the derived class has a return type (`null`) that a client of the base class would not know to expect.

That beeing said we can get pretty close to what you want.

Firstly I would not use a class with just static methods, I would create a class with instance methods, and declare a `const` of that instance type and export that for people to use as a singleton.

Secondly I would move the common functionality in a common base class, with the `readFileFromFileQuery` method being abstract and the class generic. This allows us to plug in either a version that returns `File` or one that returns `File | null` without running afoul of Typescript (and OOP) consistency rules

The final solution looks something like this (I filled in some of the types, not sure what their actual definitions are but I added what was minimally necessary for the code to be error free):

```
abstract class _FileHandlerBase<T> {
  abstract readFileFromFileQuery(fq: FileQuery): Promise<T>;
  async readFile(a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<T> {
    if (typeof a === 'string') a = FileQueryHandler.getFromPath(a, b);
    return this.readFileFromFileQuery(a);
  }
  async readFiles(a: (Path | FileQuery)[] | Directory, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<T[]> {
    if (a instanceof Array) return Promise.all(a.map(p => this.readFile(p, b)));
    return this.readFiles(PathHandler.getFromDirectory(a), b);
  }
  async readFilesFromDirectory(a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<T[]> {
    const ps = await DirectoryHandler.readDirectory(a);
    if (typeof a === 'string') return await (this).readFiles(ps, b);
    return await this.readFiles(ps, a);
  }
}
export class _FileHandler extends _FileHandlerBase<File> {
  async readFileFromFileQuery(fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
    const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
    const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
    return { path, encoding, flag, content };
  }
}
export const FileHandler = new _FileHandler();

export class _FileOrNullHandler extends _FileHandlerBase<File | null> {
  async readFileFromFileQuery(fq: FileQuery): Promise<File | null> {
    return orNull(() => FileHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(fq));
  }
}

export const FileOrNullHandler = new _FileOrNullHandler();

FileHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(null!) // Promise<File>
FileOrNullHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(null!) // Promise<File | null>

FileHandler.readFiles(null!) // Promise<File[]>
FileOrNullHandler.readFiles(null!) // Promise<(File | null)[]>

// Some assumptions
type Path = string;

interface FileQuery {
  path: string, flag?: string, encoding?: string | null
}
export interface File {
  path: string, flag?: string, encoding: string | undefined | null, content: Buffer | string
}
interface Directory {
  path: string, isDir: true
}

declare var FileQueryHandler: {
  make(fq: FileQuery): FileQuery
  getFromPath(s: string, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): FileQuery;
}

declare var DirectoryHandler : {
  readDirectory(a: Path | FileQuery) : FileQuery[]
}
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

function orNull<T>(fn: () => T) {
  try {
    return fn();
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
declare const PathHandler: {
  getFromDirectory(d: Directory): FileQuery[];
}
```